# what is condition for equations to be incompatible in system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

three equations are given
1.5x - 0.5y = 2; 4x + 2y + 3z= 9; 7x +y +5z=10;
I solve these eq using matrices as AX=B where A=
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        15 & -5 & 0 \\
        4 & 2 & 3 \\
        7 & 1 & 5 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
B= $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        20 \\
        9 \\
        10 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
X= $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        x \\
        y \\
        z \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
Inverse of A exists as Determinant is 100 thus it means solution exists. As per my calculations X= $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{7}{10} \\
        \frac{139}{20} \\
        \frac{69}{10} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
But i m shocked after seeing answer. answer is "Equations are incompatible".
I go through other examples of system of linear equations BUT m not able to find reason of incompatibility.

Comment: The solution is $\pmatrix{\frac{43}{20}\\\frac{49}{20}\\\frac{-3}{2}}$. The determinant is right, however.

Comment: If you show us the calculation, we can search for errors.

Comment: @Peter ok i m checking my calculations. But still answer is "Equations are incompatible"!!! i m not getting this point. any help!

Comment: use the Gauss algorithm to calculate the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations are compatible, because you can get an inverse for A:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
        15 & -5 & 0 \\
        4 & 2 & 3 \\
        7 & 1 & 5 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\\
A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{7}{100} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{-3}{20} \\
        \frac{1}{100} & \frac{3}{4} & \frac{-9}{20} \\
        \frac{-1}{10} & \frac{-1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
        \end{bmatrix}\\
$$
Hence:
$$
AX=B\\
A^{-1}AX=A^{-1}B\\
IX = A^{-1}B
$$
And now calculating the matrix multiplication, you get:
$$
X = \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{7}{100} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{-3}{20} \\
        \frac{1}{100} & \frac{3}{4} & \frac{-9}{20} \\
        \frac{-1}{10} & \frac{-1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
        20 \\
        9 \\
        10 \\
        \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{43}{20} \\
        \frac{49}{20} \\
        \frac{-3}{2} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
So it is compatible and has solution!